# Is it possible to export angular component as js and use as script in a legacy webpage?

Tags: node.js, angular, embed, legacy

- I have an angular 8 project. I tried to export one component of it as
  .js file.
- Is it possible to export only one component as js file?
- is it possible to embed it in a legacy webpage? perhaps as
   in head.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Angular Elements Overview](https://angular.io/guide/elements). According to the documentation, it should be possible to export only components you want.

> Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements (also called Web Components), a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way.
>
> [Custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) are a Web Platform feature currently supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari, and available in other browsers through polyfills (see [Browser Support](https://angular.io/guide/elements#browser-support)). A custom element extends HTML by allowing you to define a tag whose content is created and controlled by JavaScript code. The browser maintains a CustomElementRegistry of defined custom elements, which maps an instantiable JavaScript class to an HTML tag.